# Getting unique recently played tracks list from iPod (Music) library

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I use

```
MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *songsArray = [songsQuery items];
```

to get recently played tracks and sort the array by `MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate`
The problem is, I don't get unique plays. for example if I play song "A" and then I play song "B" and after I play "A" again, in the list I only get one item for song "A" and using the play count property gets me total plays regardless of date.
Is there anyway I can get unique plays list from the Music library?

Thanks